# How to assign the chosen variable form a tkinter dropdown widget to a variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an issue with a tkinter dropdown that does not assign the chosen value to the entry variable. I need to be able to select a string from a list of column names saved in `self.data.column`  that will then be used as argument in a `detect_cycles_irregular()` function

Here is the code:

```
tension_var = tk.StringVar()

tk.Button(cycle_types_popup, text="irregular cycles",
            command = lambda: [cycle_types_popup.destroy(), self.detect_cycles_irregular(tension_var)]).pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X, expand=0)

tk.Label(cycle_types_popup, text="Tension (N) variable: ").pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
tension_var_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(cycle_types_popup, tension_var, *self.data.columns)
tension_var_dropdown.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

And when I print `tension_var` later in the code it gives me

> tension_var =  PY_VAR7

Which is clearly not the column name I clicked on.

BONUS question: Do I need to assign the dropdown widget with the name `tension_var_dropdown` since all of this is supposed to be used only once ?

Comment: create a [mre].

Comment: You need to use `.get()` on the variable to get the actual value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning variables using choices in TKInter dropdown menu - Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380766/assigning-variables-using-choices-in-tkinter-dropdown-menu-python-2-7)